# In Texas, Can I sue if I was misled or lied to about the job I would be working

Tags: united-states, texas, workplace

I recently was recruited for a contract software engineering role with a bank.  The recruiter on several occasions through emails and phone messages emphasized this was a software engineering role. The name of the role is even in the W2 agreement.

However, after I started, I found out what I would actually be doing is significantly different and is really a different role altogether.

Is this considered fraud? I was absolutely lied to. I know in sales selling a product using incorrect information would count as fraud. Does the same apply here in being recruited for a job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I sue if I was misled or lied to about the job I would be working

Yes, but only if you can prove that your *reasonable reliance* on the employer's representations prompted to leave your former job and/or decline other projects/positions. You would need to persuade a court that your current employment (1) has worsened your circumstances in terms of compensation and/or career-wise; and, if employment is at-will, also that (2) resigning from your current job would not undo the loss you incurred as a result of taking this job position.

The particulars of your situation would determine whether your claim(s) meet the *prima facie* elements of *fraud* and/or *breach of contract*.